# Proving equality between two expressions involving sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

I'm sure my proof method is wrong, I'm having difficulty in trying to identify and express exactly what is wrong and why.

So I'm trying to prove the equivalence of the relations $B \subset A$ and $A \cup B = A$.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

To prove: $\{B \subset A\} \equiv \{A \cup B = A\}$

Given $B \subset A$,

therefore $x \in B \implies x \in A$ is true ...(1)

Proof: $x \in A \cup B$

$\implies x \in A \text{ or } x \in B$

$\implies x \in A \text{ or } x \in A$ [from (1), I think this is wrong]

$\implies x \in A$.

therefore $A \cup B = A$.

---

I can show that this is wrong.

For example, for a similar proof to show that $B \subset A$ and $A \cap B = B$ are equivalent, if I start by showing the first is a subset of the second:

To prove: $\{B \subset A\} \equiv \{A \cap B = B\}$

Given $B \subset A$,

therefore $x \in B \implies x \in A$ is true ...(1)

To prove: $x \in A \cap B$

$\implies x \in A \text{ and } x \in B$

$\implies x \in A \text{ and } x \in A$ [from (1)]

$\implies x \in A$.

therefore, $A \cap B = A$, which is the incorrect conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your solutions is incorrect. If from $x \in X$ you can prove $x \in Y$, you can only say that $X \subset Y$, not $X=Y$. To prove that $X=Y$, you can prove $X \subset Y$ and $Y \subset X$

Comment: Or $x\in X \Longleftrightarrow x\in Y$.

Comment: Yes, but this is the issue I was facing in the first step, that is, when trying to prove $X \subset Y$

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now. In the conclusion of the proof I used $=$ instead of $\subset$.